# Fixing misspellings and finding addresses in messy text

Tags: parsing, text, nlp

I’m working on a project to clean up messy social media and e-commerce order text data, and I’d like to sanity check my approach and see if there are libraries and other resources that I should consider using.

I’m processing hundreds of thousands of text snippets that are in English, but are not complete sentences, and have a mix of person names, business names, contact information, mailing addresses, and content from social media posts, including links and handles to social media handles such as Twitter and Instagram handles. The text I’m getting is just a blob of unformatted, unstructured text. I’ll point out that the text is often a jumble of phrases and words, and therefore can not be assumed to be full English sentences; I mention this because I think this may limit the amount of semantic parsing I can do with standard NLP and part of speech tagging techniques (but I’m not sure about this point).

My goals are to implement the following fixes and enhancements to each text snippet:
Fix spelling mistakes when I can confidently do so, but keep existing tokens when a confident replacement is not available. Note that there are some superfluous line breaks in my text, and sometimes missing spaces, so spelling errors come in three varieties: 1) regular misspelling (e.g., “bananna”); no space misspellings: (e.g., “yellowbanana”); extra space misspellings: (e.g., “ban ana”)
Tag addresses and place names such that I can geocode them and link to a map of that place.

Here are some made up but representative examples:

Example 1:

```
7pcs  gillette razors and 1 mens cardi
gan sweater 231 E Front St Missoula 
MT Order total $34.39 shipping ground UPS
```

In this example, I’d like to fix the misspelling of “cardigan” and also notice that “231 E Front St Missoula MT” is a mailing address.

Example 2:

```
6600 cartons yellowbanana for @metmuseum 
Marpa was a seminal figure of early Tibetan Bud
dhism and principal teacher of Milarapa
```

In this example, I’d like to fix the misspelling of “yellowbanana” and fix the misspelling of “Buddhism”

While I can certainly write a bunch of rules and regexes, I’m trying to leverage existing NLP and other tools to avoid lots of special casing. I’m looking at the following utilities so far:

- https://hunspell.github.io/ is the spellchecker that Google Chrome, Firefox, and many other projects use.
- https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/ is built on top of NLTK and seems to have many different features, although I’m not sure if it can work on my non-sentence text data to solve the above problems. This looks powerful, but I’m not sure on how exactly to leverage it for my problem.
- For Example 2, I found https://geocode.xyz/ and it’s not able to pick up on the full address (although it does get Missoula MT). https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyap also looks interesting, although it’s for just the US and Canada, and I need the ability to parse addresses around the world. I unfortunately don’t know a priori which country each text snippet is in.

I’d greatly appreciate any pointers you can give me and let me know if I’m on the right track. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple questions (or data-mining problems to solve) in your question from an NLP perspective: 1) Spell Correction, 2) Entity Extraction (which is address extraction in your case).

I will say concentrate on problem 1 i.e. Spell Correction first and then pass that Spell Corrected text to an information extractor model that solves problem 2 above.

For spell correction in your case the best bet is a probabilistic framework that learns from the data (specifically your data). At the moment the best probabilistic/Machine-Learning based spell correctors are Deep Neural Network based models. See here -- https://medium.com/@majortal/deep-spelling-9ffef96a24f6 Here is the code https://github.com/MajorTal/DeepSpell (and an improvement over it https://hackernoon.com/improving-deepspell-code-bdaab1c5fb7e). You can start form standard spell correction data, and then probably add some of your own hand crafted training data to tune the model for your specific case.

Now for Entity Extraction, given its not well formed text, start from models that train off social media text such as twitter, and other online forums e.g. http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ark/TweetNLP/ and https://github.com/aritter/twitter_nlp and take it from there, and tune them by adding your own labeled data and parameter tweaks.

Answer (score 0):

Your first example on geocoder.ca:
https://geocoder.ca/?scantext=7pcs%20gillette%20razors%20and%201%20mens%20cardi%20gan%20sweater%20231%20E%20Front%20St%20Missoula%20MT%20Order%20total%20$34.39%20shipping%20ground%20UPS

Gives this response:
Match   Location
1
x Found 3 locations in this line:

7pcs gillette razors and 1 mens cardi gan sweater 231 E1 Front1 St1 Missoula1 MT Order total $34.39 shipping ground UPS

- 399, FRONT ST E, MISSOULA, MT (Confidence: 0.32)
- 399, FRONT ST W, MISSOULA, MT (Confidence: 0.32)
- FRONT ST E, MISSOULA, MT (Confidence: 0.31)